# Resize to particular size while maintain aspect ratio in css

Tags: html, css

I am loading a while bunch of photos onto my page and they are all different sizes. I need to bring them all down to the same size* (which is: x200px by y400px) _while maintaining aspect ratio.

How do I do this in pure CSS?

Comment: *different sizes* may have *different ratios*, but you want them to be scaled down **to the same size** and their ratios are still maintained? It's impossible. They should have the same ratio for sure.

Comment: @KingKing I understand. I was having difficulty getting out what I meant. What I meant was, I know they can't all be the same size, I meant that I want to scale them down, ah, i can't explain it! Do you know what I mean now? Um... Ok, if we have 2 pics, one is really long (in height) and the other is really wide, then i want the really wide one to be scaled so its width matches my maximum width (200px) rule and i want the really long one to match the height of my maxaimum height rule (400px)

Answer (score 6):

The following CSS class will restrict them to the sizes you specified. diffferent aspect ratios may have smaller height or width but the aspect ratio is maintained

```
.yourimage{

width:200px;
height:400px;
background-image: url("yourimage.png");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-position: center ;



}
```

here is a fiddle with example
http://jsfiddle.net/LgZtD/

Answer (score 3):

CSS cannot change the sizes of your images, that's not what it is for. You will lose the aspect ratio if you insert the images into img tags with width:200px and height:40ppx.

What you can do though is use CSS to show a 200px x 400px element with the image as a background, and then use the background-size property to have the image cover the 200px x 400px space. CSS will find the most efficient way to cover that area without changing the size of the image

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(/url/to/image);
    background-size: cover; //This will cover the area of the image
    background-position: center center; //Have the image centered
}
```

http://codepen.io/herihehe/full/aLwGt

This is a great example of what you want. Look at the difference between contain and cover. Contain shows the actual size of the image. Cover "covers" the area

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rnb/)